# Do bcrypt minor version generates (2b vs 2a) generate different salt?

Tags: security, hash, bcrypt, salt, crypt

So depending on the minor version of the bcrypt it will execute different hash computations as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

However, do salt gen has any differences between the versions apart from setting the minor and major? Is it just pure random string based on the specific length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salt is just a random string, it should vary every time you generate a password hash regardless of the 2a/2b scheme. Salts should prevent people from build dictionaries of common plaintext and hash combinations.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. After digging around could not find anything that would disprove that. I was hoping that someone will point to the source code of the c libs for the completion sake.

Comment: * https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt
* https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference between 2, 2a, 2x, 2y, 2b.

And for the all the reasons that the different versions exist, none of them change the salt in any way - it's still purely random. Some are not more random than others.

Source: the source.

Comment: What are the reasons that the different versions exist?